# Log Cleaning in R

Tags: r, text-analysis

this is the structure of a log template which I have loaded in R. How do I clean it to make a dataframe?

```
{"ask":{"Id":001,"TS":10012001,"Response":"12"}}
{"ask":{"Id":002,"TS":11012001,"Response":"10"}}
```

The expected output is should be individual columns with their values in a data frame for further analysis.

Comment: Perhaps `rjson::fromJSON`? (I'm mobile, so suggesting based on the structure of your strings )

Answer (score 1):

Since the lines are almost valid JSON except for the leading zero-numbered string that should be wrapped in quotes, consider cleaning for valid JSON and import as one-row dataframes with jsonlite. Then row bind all individual df elements in list. Below iteratively reads lines in log to convert each line:

```
library(jsonlite)

loglines <- readLines("/path/to/log.txt")

dfList <- lapply(loglines, function(line){
  # JSON CONVERT WITH QUOTE AND BRACKET WRAPPING
  jsonline <- paste0("[", gsub(',"TS', '","TS', gsub('Id":', 'Id":"', line)), "]")

  fromJSON(jsonline)[[1]]
})

df <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(V8)
library(jqr)
library(tidyverse)

txt <- '{"ask":{"Id":001,"TS":10012001,"Response":"12"}}
{"ask":{"Id":002,"TS":11012001,"Response":"10"}}'

lines <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
```

#### V8 helper

```
ctx <- v8()
map_df(lines, function(x) {
  ctx$eval(sprintf("var dat=%s", JS(x)))
  ctx$get("dat") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    as.list()
})
## # A tibble: 2 × 3
##   ask.Id   ask.TS ask.Response
##    <chr>    <chr>        <chr>
## 1      1 10012001           12
## 2      2 11012001           10
```

#### jqr + jsonlite helper

```
map(lines, jq, ".") %>%
  map(jsonlite::fromJSON) %>%
  map(unlist) %>%
  map_df(as.list)
## # A tibble: 2 × 3
##   ask.Id   ask.TS ask.Response
##    <chr>    <chr>        <chr>
## 1      1 10012001           12
## 2      2 11012001           10
```

#### jqr + ndjson helper

```
map(lines, jq, ".") %>%
  map(flags, pretty=FALSE) %>%
  map_df(~ndjson::flatten(.$data))
## Source: local data table [2 x 3]
## 
## # tbl_dt [2 × 3]
##   ask.Id ask.Response   ask.TS
##    <dbl>        <chr>    <dbl>
## 1      1           12 10012001
## 2      2           10 11012001
```

`mutate()` + `sprintf()` your leading `0`'s back if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Here a a quick solution:

1.Read the entire file as character array:

```
sfile <- readLines(file)
```

2.Use `gsub` to clean the `sfile`, assuming the exact structure from your original example:

```
sfile <- gsub("{ \"ask\": { \"Id\":| \"TS\":| \"Response\":\"|\" }}", "", sfile, perl = TRUE)
```

3.Now read it as commma separated value (`read.csv` accepts as input a string instead of a file)

```
df <- read.csv(file=sfile)
```

4.Name the columns

```
names(df) <- c("Id", "TS", "Response")
```

Here a test using an array instead of an input file:

```
s <- c( '{ "ask": { "Id":001, "TS":10012001, "Response":"12" }}',
        '{ "ask": { "Id":002, "TS":11012001, "Response":"10" }}'
      )
```

Now you get a comma separated value array of characters

```
> gsub("{ \"ask\": { \"Id\":| \"TS\":| \"Response\":\"|\" }}", "", s, perl = TRUE)
[1] "001,10012001,12" "002,11012001,10"
```